# Debugging an Out of Memory Error in Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, google-cloud-platform, out-of-memory

I'm currently working on a Node.js project and my server keeps running out of memory. It has happened 4 times in the last 2 weeks, usually after about 10,000 requests. This project is live and has real users.

I am using

- NodeJS 16
- Google Cloud Platform's App Engine (instances have 2048mb of memory)
- Express as my server framework
- TypeORM as database ORM (database is postgres hosted on separate GCP SQL instance)

I have installed the [GCP profiling tools](https://cloud.google.com/profiler/docs/profiling-nodejs#app-engine) and have captured the app running out of memory, but I'm not quite sure how to use the results. It almost looks like there is a memory leak in the `_handleDataRow` function within the pg client library. I am currently using version 8.8.0 of the library (8.9.0 was just released a few weeks ago and doesn't mention fixing any memory leaks in the release notes).

I'm a bit stuck with what I should do at this point.

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update**: I have also cross-posted to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/112jk41/comment/j8om0bg/?context=3) and someone there helped me determine that issue is related to large queries with many joins. I was able to reproduce the issue, and will report back here once I am able to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the package [@google-cloud/debug-agent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@google-cloud/debug-agent). There is an open [issue](https://github.com/googleapis/cloud-debug-nodejs/issues/811) about the package causing a memory leak. Many people have had this issue.

Answer (score 1):

When using `App Engine`, a great place to start looking for "why" a problem occurred in your app is through the [Logs Explorer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query). Particularly, if you know the time-frame of when the issues started escalating or when the crash occurred.

Although based on your `Memory Usage` graph, it's a slow leak. So a top-to-bottom approach of your back-end is really necessary to try and pin-point the culprit. I would go through the whole stack and look for things like `Globals` that are set and not cleaned up, promises that are not being returned, large result-sets from the database that are bottle-necking the server, perhaps from a scheduled task.

Looking at the 2pm - 2:45pm range on the right-hand of the graph, I would narrow the Logs Explorer down to that exact time-frame. Then I would look for the processes or endpoints that are being utilized most frequently in that time-frame as well as the ones that are taking the most memory to get a good starting point.